# How to type like a human via Actionchains send_keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, sendkeys

I know how to type slowly with the next code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mainCommentForm")
text = "To type text here"
for character in text:
  elem.send_keys(character)
  time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2,0.5))
```

Unfortunately, the website where I work with does not allow to type text via the normal send_keys option, as it gives an error message. It is like I select the element, then I want to send_keys but it cannot find the element as it is deselected or something. It has something to do with typing in Java. Please do not ask why this is not working as that is not my question..

Fact is, I need to use the Actionchains send_keys option as seen below.
But how do I simulate typing as a human now, same as example above?
By human typing I mean typing it in letter by letter instead of just copy/paste..

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mainCommentForm")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elem)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys("This text must be typed in slower..")
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Why you think that site *"does not allow to type text via the normal send_keys "*?

Comment: What do you mean with like a human? Human can paste the text and it will be like `send_keys()`

Comment: `ActionChains.send_keys()` and `WebElement.send_keys()` doing the same actions "under the hood". What makes you think the website doesn't allow this?

Comment: @Guy I edited my question so it is more clear.. The WebElement.send_keys() gives me an error message.. I MUST use ActionChains.send_keys()

Comment: elem.send_keys("This text must be typed in slower..")

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? I see no real reason why your code would not work

Comment: What error message does it give? Understanding why it's not working is part of providing the best answer... there's no reason we shouldn't ask that and/or try to figure it out. Post a link to the page so we can take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code works the way you want -

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("mainCommentForm")
text = "To type text here"
for character in text:
  actions = ActionChains(driver)
  actions.move_to_element(elem)
  actions.click()
  actions.send_keys(character)
  print(character)
  actions.perform()
  time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2,0.5))
```

Comment: END BOSS! Thank you, that works!

NOTE: If you notice that it types strange all of a sudden, use the move element with offset. Below moves to offset X 450.

    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 450, 0)

Comment: @Romano not sure about the offset since you haven't provided the URL but glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

**In python if you want to type something like real human just use this code the dealy between every character will be random**

```
 for char in text:
        start = 0.1 #please edit the speed here
        stop = 0.6 #change this (the maximum value is 1 or 0.9)
        step = 0.3
        precision = 0.1
        f = 1 / precision
        n = random.randrange(start * f, stop * f, step * f) / f
        time.sleep(n)
        user_input.send_keys(char)
```